# Recent post thumbnail not show in mobile

Tags: wordpress, macos

I am using the latest version of Wordpress. In sidebar and footer I used the recent post widget but in mobile and MAC OS the post thumbnails could not be shown. How can I solve this the problem?

Comment: Share your website URL

Comment: http://gosafir.com

Comment: http://gosafir.com/safir/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/khbar-01-110x96@2x.jpg -> 403 forbiden, make sure the images have public read access

Comment: you are referring about the "AMBASSADOR"(translation) widget in the footer?

Comment: The photos are public. In Windows I don't have this problem.

Comment: You can visit my website in English version : [link] (http://gosafir.com/en)  .  I am talking about the Recent Posts in sidebar and Cinema News in footer.

Comment: In which device and in which browser you are facing issues?

Comment: In mobile devices and MAC os

Comment: you can try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/recent-posts-widget-with-thumbnails/screenshots/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best dimensions for blog posts featured image is 750 x 350 Pixels.

When you enter the single post/page as per our theme there is no featured image to display. The feature which you require for your site needs lots of code customization work, which we could not cover through this forum. Hope you can understand. But, if you can code it by yourself, then, please prefer doing so using the child theme..
Other wise you can try this plugin [Recent Posts Widget With Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/recent-posts-widget-with-thumbnails/screenshots/)